# how to wrap text in table cell-xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo

i used the following xsl for table creation. i used the wrap-option for the text wrap but i am not able to wrap the the text. long text goes into the next column.

```
              <xsl:template
    match="ENTRY">
    <fo:table-cell
        wrap-option="wrap"
        padding="2px"
        border-bottom="03px"
        border-collapse="collapse">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when
                test="@MOREROWS">
                <xsl:attribute
                    name="number-rows-spanned">
            <xsl:value-of
                    select="@MOREROWS" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when
                test="@COLSPAN">
                <xsl:attribute
                    name="number-columns-spanned">
            <xsl:value-of
                    select="@COLSPAN" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try your 'wrap-option' attribute within

```
  <fo:block>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
```